# How to display a contact address on Google maps offline?

Tags: contacts, google-maps

For each contact there is a personal address field which can be filled with informations like street name, city, country, and so on. The problem is that in order to display these informations on a map, Google maps have to do an online search to get the coordinates. How can I use this feature offline ?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is: you can't.

The feature relies on a service called [geocoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding), which is done on Google's servers. The only possibility for this to be done locally would be to download the entire map data to the device and use that data to calculate the coordinates from an address. This is a resource and space consuming task (for example, OpenStreetMap has a dataset of 370GB), and not suitable for mobiles.

<strike>A workaround would be to save the coordinates themselves as a street address in the form `latitude,longitude`, e.g. `62.244858,25.758712` in addition to the regular address and use this "address" to show the map. The catch is, you'd still have to use a geocoder to resolve the address to coordinates.</strike>

All address fields are sent to Google to be resolved, that's why the workaround I suggested is invalid.

Comment: I don't understand why Google maps don't give me the option to cache this result. A simple GPS coordinate would be enough, even though Google maps don't work offline (for navigation)

Comment: @Antoine see the update for a workaround, that's the best I can come up with.

Comment: In which field do you put this string? So far it stills require an internet connection to display it on a map.

Comment: Ok, so it appears that the Contacts app sends all address queries to Google to be resolved. So it can't be done this way either. Just so you know, the Contacts app creates a `formattedAddress` query from the address, and the location you'll have to put the coordinates differs between Contacts apps, for me the Street address field worked.